# asp.net mvc 3 radiobuttonfor doens't have repeatdirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What should I do to render my list vertically , 
also I want the text to come on the left of the radio button

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HowDidYouHear, "سمعت عن الملتقى من خلال")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @foreach (var opt in Model.HowDidYouHear)
            {          
                <label for="opt">@opt</label>

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedHowDidYouHear, opt, new { id = opt })
            }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an inner div. In foreach loop

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HowDidYouHear, "سمعت عن الملتقى من خلال")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @foreach (var opt in Model.HowDidYouHear)
    {          
        <div>
            <label for="opt">@opt</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedHowDidYouHear, opt, new { id = opt })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```